# Scrapy: TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'settings'

Tags: python, scrapy

I have a Scrapy middleware:

```
class ProxyMiddleware(object):
    def __init__(self, settings):
        self.proxy_file = settings.get('PROXY_FILE')
        fin = open(self.proxy_file)
        self.proxy_list = list()
        for line in fin.readlines():
            parts = line.strip().split()
            proxy = parts[2] + '://' + parts[0] + ':' + parts[1]
            self.proxy_list.append(proxy)

    def process_request(self, request, spider):
        request.meta['proxy'] = random.choice(self.proxy_list)
```

But an error occurred when running, what's the settings?

Comment: Where do you create an instance of this class?

Comment: I didn't instantiation the class

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'settings'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need a `settings` object to initialize your middleware, you need to define a `from_crawler()` class method, [otherwise scrapy initializes the middleware without arguments](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/129421c7e31b89b9b0f9c5f7d8ae59e47df36091/scrapy/middleware.py#L40).

Take a look at the built-in middleware for inspiration, for example [`HttpErrorMiddleware`](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/ce8a9aadc969d9e999300b8b3a568f7c287e2e6a/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/httperror.py#L24)

```
class HttpErrorMiddleware(object):

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
        return cls(crawler.settings)

    def __init__(self, settings):
        self.handle_httpstatus_all = settings.getbool('HTTPERROR_ALLOW_ALL')
        self.handle_httpstatus_list = settings.getlist('HTTPERROR_ALLOWED_CODES')
```

In your case it would be something like:

```
class ProxyMiddleware(object):

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
        return cls(crawler.settings)

    def __init__(self, settings):
        self.proxy_file = settings.get('PROXY_FILE')
        fin = open(self.proxy_file)
        self.proxy_list = list()
        for line in fin.readlines():
            parts = line.strip().split()
            proxy = parts[2] + '://' + parts[0] + ':' + parts[1]
            self.proxy_list.append(proxy)

    def process_request(self, request, spider):
        request.meta['proxy'] = random.choice(self.proxy_list)
```